# Will a Jenkins pipeline compile twice when building a tag?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to setup a Jenkins pipeline which builds a Docker image whenever Jenkins is building a tag, so I used `buildingTag()` in the `when` condition. This works fine but I have some trouble understanding Jenkins at this point.

Every commit triggers the "Compile" stage. If a tag is built, will the "Compile" stage be executed twice? In a first run on the e.g. `master` branch and in a second run when explicitly starting the "Tag" build job? If so, how could this be avoided?

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        APP_NAME = 'myapp'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Compile') {
            steps {
                echo "Start compiling..."
            }
        }
        stage('Build Docker Image') {
            when { buildingTag() }
            steps {
                echo "Building a Docker image..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a multibranch project branch builds are separate from tag builds, so yes, each build would have the compile stage running. They will also have separate workspaces, so they should not affect each other.

If you don't want a stage to run at tag build, just add a `when { not { buildingTag() } }` expression to that stage.